# Facebook SDK with Codeigniter and Codeigniter CSRF Enabled

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I followed this tutorial here:
http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

It works great but when I enable CSRF protection I no longer get the info back from facebook. How can I use Codeigniter CSRF protection and the facebook sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive CI-3 offers a whitelist for turning CSRF on / off .

Until then you might need to hack the config file.
Check to see what class is in the uri then run a conditional based on the result to turn CSRF on / off.

Answer (score 2):

if you're still looking for something to help, i created a class to do just this and posted it an github. -> https://github.com/hack4lk/CodeIgniter-CSRF-for-Facebook